# Which of these is better practice for CRUD? Simple.Data or Dapper?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, orm, dapper, simple.data

I'm using both Dapper and simple.Data in my application, Dapper for retrieving data only and other operations by Simple.Data. I just need to know if using Simple.Data is better approach in all operations except retrieval and is it the same in performance like using ExecuteNonQuery in Dapper?

Comment: "Better" is a very subjective word...

Comment: Why don't you measure the performance? Noone but yourself can tell if your app runs faster with method X or Y.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sometimes it is better to learn from persons who are more experienced than you, I think one of the objectives of this site is that point. Perhaps somebody like you can advice me to use something else or tell me I'm wrong or my question is wrong in this way.

Comment: If you are comfortable with dynamic, then go with Simple.Data. I like Dapper better because of the speed and the support it has in the community (it has some good extensions for ex: https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I would suggest Simple.Data. This is mostly because Simple.Data has support for CRUD operations out of the box. (https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/wiki/Inserting-and-updating-data). They are both extremely fast, but I think for an application doing mostly CRUDs, I would pick Simple.Data out of those two.

You may also want to consider ORMLite. Anything from the ServiceStack library is fantastic.

Thanks. Happy Coding!

Comment: ...or PetaPoco for what it's worth. Very developer friendly and very fast as well.

Comment: Simple.Data is very elegant and satisfying to use. For a small application where performance is not critical I'd use it every time. However, Dapper wins out in performance all round and if I wanted to be absolutely sure of performance I'd create a Dapper repo, for example:  http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-dapper-orm-with-asp-net-core/.

Comment: So you could use Simple.Data for most operations and then bring in Dapper where performance is critical. Either way you'd have a manageable solution without all the bloat and performance issues of EF.

Answer (score 0):

Both have CRUD support now, so if you made an investment in Dapper, just add one of these nugets and you're good to go!

1. Dapper.[Extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions)
2. Dapper with Rainbow
3. Dapper.[Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib) over 5K users starred this!!!